# Powershell Get-Content ReadCount maintains sequence of records?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am using Powershell to process a text file and this is the sample code I am trying to use.

```
Get-Content -ReadCount 10 $FilePath | foreach {...
```

What am I concerned about is, will `ReadCount` maintain the exact sequence of records as they are in the source file, while sending them to the foreach as arrays?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will maintain the exact sequence of records

Comment: Thanks a lot Angelique for the reply :).
Request you to please share some MSDN or other references if available...